# RoR - Facet Filtering approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facet

I have a Ruby on Rails web application that provides users with a search/filter functionality. Basically I am trying to program towards this kind of app.
http://demo.srchulo.com/jquery/jquery_facets/

However, I am using ActiveRecord (No Elasticsearch or Solr) for searching. Now I have read that Elasticsearch and Solr supports facet search and facet filtering. Thus, I wonder do I need to implement Elasticsearch or Solr in order for facets filtering or can I achieve that by a simple Javascript Query? I would like to avoid Elasticsearch or Solr if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think sql can do that with a lot of and and having and group by ;P

Answer (score 0):

you are completely mixing all the technologies here.

- javascript/jquery -> client side browser scripting
- active-record -> serverside (relational) database (mysql?) ORM (object relational mapper)
- solr/elasticsearch -> serverside fulltext-search services

and the overall answer to your question is: it depends!

i guess you need to provide a) way more context information b) figure out what exactly you need for your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a gem to create simple ActiveRecord based facet searches.

As stated above it uses `group by` and `having` clauses to gather information about the facet values and provides a simple API to access the facets and create links to narrowed down results.

In your view you can iterate the result like any other ActiveRecord collection

```
%table.table.table-condensed
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td
          %strong=movie.title

Use the search object to display further narrowing options to the user

- filter = @search.filter(:genre)
.col-md-4
  .filter
    .filter-title= filter.name
    .filter-values
      %ul.selected
        - filter.selected.each do |genre|
          %li= link_to genre.name, filter.remove(genre).path
      %ul.selectable
        - filter.facet.reject(&:selected).each do |facet_value|
          - genre = facet_value.genre
          %li
            = link_to genre.name, filter.add(genre).path
            %span.count= "(#{facet_value.count})"
```

https://github.com/fortytools/forty_facets

Comment: When do you typically see scaling issues with forty facets?

Comment: It's hard to come up with general metrics since the actual speed depends on your schema and your data.
The filtering is done via pretty straight forward joins and where(...) queries.
So everything you do in your normal controller methods to speed up queries applies here to
For each Facet there happens one 'GROUP-BY' query. These can vary greatly in cost depending on number of facets and facet values.
I don't consider myself a DB expert, but with just slapping indices on all relevant columns I've had no issues filtering on datasets with up to 100K rows of 'base' entities and 4-5 facets.